# Overflow in addition

Tags: vba, excel

```
String A = String B + String C
```

where String B and C are numbers but stored in form of text and String A should contain sum of both and not concatenate both, which it does, so I used,

```
String A= Cint(String B) + Cint( String C)
```

It throws an overflow error. Enjoy the weekend.

Comment: What values are in your strings?  CInt converts to 16 bit signed integer so chances are your values are out of that range.

Comment: And also how is your `String A` Declared?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Dim String A As String

Comment: @chrisneilsen Numbers are small. Eg. 5,425,894.01

Comment: Then see the answer posted :)

Answer (score 5):

`Cint` converts to an `Integer` type, that would throw an overflow exception if the result is greater than 32767

Use `CDbl` (or `CLng`) instead of `CInt` to convert the string values to `Double`

```
Dim a as String,b as String, c as String
a="1234567"
b="9876543"
c=CDbl(a)+CDbl(b)
```

Comment: @Uri Goren That worked. Thanks. It would be great if you could tell that why didn't it work for Integer? As the only difference between the two would have been in rounding the numbers

Comment: You could also use `CLng` to convert to `Long` which is also an integer type